# C segmentation fault error in some test cases

Tags: c, scanf

Not able to understand why on some particular test cases it returns segmentation faults while on others it is accepted.Please suggest.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
        int n,i,j,k,count=0,r;
        scanf("%i",&n);
        char string[500000];
        scanf("%s",&string[i]);
        int sqr[500000];
        sqr[0]=0;
        for(i=1;i<=n+1;i++)
        {
            sqr[i]=i*i;
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(r=1;r<=n+1;r++)
            {
                if((sqr[r]%(i+1))==0)
                {
                    k=(sqr[r]/(i+1))-1;
                    j=r-1;
                    int tempi = (int) string[i];
                    int tempj = (int) string[j];
                    int tempk = (int) string[k];
                    if(tempi==97 && tempj==98 && tempk==99) count++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%i",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char string[500000];` are you serious?

Comment: `i` is uninitialized when `scanf("%s",&string[i]);`

Comment: Are you sure it is only on *some* test cases ?

Comment: Why don't you read the compiler's warnings?

Comment: thanks,i got the problem!

Comment: actually i had edited my previous code written long time back>

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes i am sure.

Comment: i did the following changes and replaced ` scanf("%s",&string[i]);` With:
` for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                scanf("%s",&string[i]);
            }` 
still getting segmentation error.??

Comment: You probably want `scanf("%s",string);` instead of `scanf("%s",&string[i]);`. Please give us an example of input and expected output, just to be sure.

Comment: Running the test cases in a debugger should reveal exactly where the segfaults are occurring, and furthermore should allow you to examine your variables' values at the point of the crashes.  You might also consider running your test cases under a memory usage analyzer such as Valgrind.

Comment: What does the variable `string` represent?  Be careful with +1 indexing.  Not sure why you have `n+1`?

Comment: `if(tempi==97 && tempj==98 && tempk==99)` doesn't make a sense since the code is `(int)string[i]`, the returned value is a single digit, not a double digit.

Comment: Please provide inputs and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 scanf("%s",&string[i]);
```

`i` has indeterminate value. There's no guarantee the pointer arithmetic is valid. It can make the pointer point to anywhere, including invalid memory. Attempt to access that causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, some general advice

- `int main()` should be `int main(void)` to be conforming for hosted environment.
- Always check the return value of `scanf()`.
- use maximum field width while scanning strings to avoid buffer overrun.
- Keep local variable with automatic storage with explicit initialization added for them.

Comment: replaced this with `scanf("%s",&string[i])` with `scanf("%s",string);` still same error.

Comment: @NagendraJha what is your input?? What excactly is your test case? Tell us more if you want good answers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz sir, actually my SPOJ is not showing the test cases so i will not be able to give you those.

Comment: @NagendraJha OK, then please just show us the input _you_ enter when you run the program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz can i create a string with variable length of character taken during run time??
spoj doesnot gives the inputs too,it just gives how many test cases you passed and how many you failed.

Comment: @NagendraJha sigh....if I run your program, what am I supposed to type?